# Pass arguments in redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I want to pass an argument in redux but I didn't found the way to do it.

Here's my code:

redux/actions

```js
export const next_page = (max_page) => {
    return {
        type: NEXT_PAGE,
        payload: max_page
    }
}
```

redux/middleware

```js
export const update_page = (dispatch) => next => action => {
    next(action)
    if (action.type === NEXT_PAGE) {
      dispatch(next_page({max_page: action.payload}))
    } 
}
```

redux/reducer

```js
export default (page = 1, action) => {
    switch (action.payload) {
        case NEXT_PAGE:
            const nextPage = page + 1
            return nextPage <= action.payload ? nextPage : page
        default:
            return page
    }
}
```

Calling the component

```js
<ChangePage max={this.state.max_pages} {...{prevPage, nextPage, page}} />

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  page: state.page,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  nextPage: () => dispatch(next_page()),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

ChangePage component

```js
<button onClick={() => this.props.nextPage(max_page)}>Next</button>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the argument max_page to use it in redux/reducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass `max_page` through your `nextPage` prop in `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  nextPage: max_page => dispatch(next_page(max_page)),
})
```

Then, when you invoke it inside of the `ChangePage` component your `max_page` argument will already be passed through.

In addition, note that you don't need a middleware to re-dispatch the action again (this will result in an infinite loop):

```
// Just delete the middleware
```

And your reducer should be switching on `action.type`, not `action.payload`:

```
// redux/reducer
export default (page = 1, action) => {
    switch (action.type) { // changed from action.payload
        case NEXT_PAGE:
            const nextPage = page + 1
            return nextPage <= action.payload ? nextPage : page
        default:
            return page
    }
}
```